# visualworks smalltalk: how can I detect substring from a string, is it possible?

Tags: string, substring, smalltalk, visualworks

as title suggests I'm not sure best route to detect the presence of a substring in a string, for example:

```
OverExtended:anErrorMessage

"anErrorMessage = 'error: robot arm extended too far' "

(anErrorMessage **contains:** 'extended too far')
ifTrue:[
   ...
   ...
]
ifFalse:[
   ...
   ...
].
```

Now I know the above doesnt work, but is there an existing method for checking for substrings??

Comment: it should be noted that incomming text can be variable so I cannot simply look via character index (ie from 18 to: end is equal to 'extended too far' as some may contain more at the tail end or front end)

Comment: You also might say which version you’re using. Always helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer that is both simple and accurate in all scenarios w/o dependancy on readStreams or extentions to 'naitive' VW as far back as VW7.4:

simply use **findString:startingAt:** and do a greater then zero check for # of occurences

sample:

```
|string substring1 substring2|
string:= 'The Quick Brown Fox'.
substring1:= 'quick'.
substring2:='Quick'.

"below returns FALSE as 'quick' isnt found"
(string findString: substring1 startingAt:1)>0
ifTrue:[^'found [quick]'].

"below returns TRUE as 'Quick' is found"
(string findString: substring2 startingAt:1)>0
ifTrue:[^'found [Quick]'].

^'found nothing'.
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be dialect dependent, so try the following

```
'Smalltalk' includesSubstring: 'mall' --> true
'Smalltalk' includesSubstring: 'malta' --> true

'Smalltalk' indexOfSubCollection: 'mall' --> 2
'Smalltalk' indexOfSubCollection: 'malta' --> 0
```

(see Bob's comment below)

```
'Smalltalk' indexOfSubCollection: 'mall' startingAt: 1 --> 2
'Smalltalk' indexOfSubCollection: 'malta' startingAt: 1 --> 0
```

You may want to add one of the above to your image e.g.

```
String >> includesString: aString
  ^(self indexOfSubCollection: aString: startingAt: 1) > 0
```

Comment: CharacterArray>>includesSubString: and SequenceableCollection>>indexOfSubCollection: are both Grease extensions.
But CharacterArray>>indexOfSubCollection:startingAt: is base VW code. 
VW really should have added more utility methods like these to the base VW code.

Comment: @BobNemec Thanks! If added your comment to my answer.

Comment: Good, but you probably mean (self indexOf...) > 0

Comment: @aka.nice Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try `#match:`, like so: `'*fox*' match: 'there''s a fox in the woods'`. There're two kinds of wildcards: `*` and `#`. `#` matches any single character. `*` matches any number of characters (including none).

`#match:` defaults to case-insensitive matching, if you need case-sensitive, use `#match:ignoringCase:` and pass `false` as second argument.

Answer (score 2):

Match works fine in VisualWorks,  but I add a utility method to string:

includesSubString: aString

```
| readStream |
readStream := self readStream.
readStream upToAll: aString.
^readStream atEnd not
```

Comment: What if `aString` occurs at the end of the receiver? The `readStream` will also be positioned `atEnd`. Right?

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia no, `upToAll:` leaves the stream positionned **before** next occurrence. you must be thinking in term of `thoughAll:` which leaves the stream past the next occurrence

Comment: @aka.nice I don't know how it works in VW (that's why I asked). In some dialects, including Pharo, `#upToAll:` leaves the position right after the argument, if it finds it. Therefore, if this is the case and the argument occurs at the end of the receiver, the stream will be positioned `atEnd` and the method will fail. If `#upToAll:` is different in VW, then the code above do work as expected.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia uh, you're right, I never noticed the difference before! In Squeak/Pharo/Cuis it leaves the stream positioned AFTER the occurrence. `'tic tac toe' readStream upToAll: 'tac'; upToEnd.`-> `' toe'` but `'tac toe'` in VW. In VW, `upTo:$c` leaves the stream positioned after the next occurrence of Character `$c`, so maybe VW is not that logic with itself...